# How do I make this sentence complete?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, conjugations

Sentence to be corrected: **All the while improving their society for the next generation.**

It doesn't seem to be a complete sentence? Because I thought that "all the while" acts more like a conjunction, but here there would only be one clause. I must correct this sentence without any other context and without adding any new information. Any ideas for doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: You are correct. An independent clause requires a finite (tensed) verb.

Answer (score 1):

> I must correct this sentence without any other context and without adding any new information.

Not really possible.  This fragment is a modifier, so it wants to modify something.  What that something is could be anything.

You can convert it into a standalone sentence by adding a subject and changing *improving* to accordingly, but you have no way of knowing the right subject to use.

> All the while they improved their society for the next generation.

Or you can use a progressive/continuous tense if you don't want to change any of the existing words:

> All the while they were improving their society for the next generation.